# ReactJS - Javascript run on browser but not in class App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building a React project, I'm introducing a js code which is needed to display a popup properly. The code from the beginning is for clearing the URL from (#nameOfThePopup) and is introducing 2 functions : Close() and Open().

It runs just great in a normal HTML page, but when i want to fill it in my React project, it does some compilation problems, specificly 2 lines:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
event.stopPropagation();
```

I did try to make it in ComponentDidmount() method and introduce it in public index.html as a script but still the same compilation errors.

There is my full code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Popup extends React.Component {


  /*Clear URL from #popup1 in the end*/
  history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');       /*<=== error compile*/

  /*declar variables and clear the popup from the DOM*/
  let id_popup = document.querySelector('#popup1');
let popup = id_popup.parentNode; 
popup.removeChild(id_popup);



/*Opening the popup */
Open() {
  popup.appendChild(id_popup);
  event.stopPropagation();                   /*<=== error compile*/
  let class_popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
  window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    if (!class_popup.contains(e.target)) {
      Close();
    }
  });
}


/*Closing the popup */
 Close() {
  popup.removeChild(id_popup);
  history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
}


  render() {
      return (
<div>
 <input type="submit" onClick={this.Open} />
  <title>test popup</title>
  <div id="popup1" className="overlay">
    <div className="popup">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <a className="close" onClick={this.Close} href="javascript://">
        ×
      </a>
      <div className="content">
        my popup content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


      )

  }


}




export default Popup;
```

Css :

```
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .popup {
    margin: 70px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .popup h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .popup .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
  }

  .popup .close:hover {
    color: #06D85F;
  }

  .popup .content {
    height: 60%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .box {
      width: 70%;
    }

    .popup {
      width: 70%;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your app rendered on the server?

Comment: "some compilation problems"... Perhaps it would make sense to actually enumerate those problems. In your class you have random code executing outside of any function, and you attempt to reference a variable inside a function when there's no variable of that name in scope.

Comment: @AlexandreSenges yes, of course.

Comment: @aliouawalid Really? I doubt that--this code, besides being very non-Reactish, doesn't show that there's the requisite knowledge that would be required to implement SSR. Your code is completely broken--at the JS level, ignoring anything regarding React.

Comment: @DaveNewton I did said where the compilation stuck, and the code outside the function needs to be executed first at the starting, maybe i should add a function then what ? would that solve the problem ? this code works just fine, that's not the problem

Comment: @aliouawalid You said it "stuck" on those "two lines", presented as contiguous code, which is not how the code actually is. You didn't say *what* the compilation errors were. If the code "works just fine" then you wouldn't need to post--obviously the code does *not* work "just fine". Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: It has *everything* to do with JavaScript. I told you what the problems were, the answer told you what the problems were. You cannot blindly cut and paste non-React code and put it in random locations in a React component and expect it to work: you're referring to variables that do not exist in the context you're trying to use them, and putting code where it makes no sense. These are *explicitly* related to JS, not React. There are *also* issues related to your React code quite apart from the JS issues.

Comment: And again: showing two lines saying "the errors come from these two lines only" is not diagnostic: you do not include the errors, and you take the lines out of context making it even *more* difficult to understand what the problems might be (even though you've been told twice why they are errors). Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What you consider "arrogant" are the basic SO posting guidelines as outlined in the FAQ, and common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your component is rendered on the server, if it is the case,   `history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');` won't compile because `history` is a member of `window` which does not exist on the server. So you will need to check if your code is running on the server or the client, there are different ways to do this depending on the SSR framework you are using, for instance nextjs provides `process.browser` which is true if on the client or undefined in node:

```
if(process.browser) window.history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
```

Then for your `event.stopPropagation` part, event is not defined anywhere in the code you provided, so there must be a problem in your implementation (maybe add it to the function parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i execute this code, in my case console.log(process.browser) returns true, what's the meaning ? the condition don't work, when i refresh i get the same path.

Comment: Is that what you're talking about ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs

Comment: @aliouawalid It's because if the code is running on the server (during the ssr phase), it won't have access to window.history, therefore, it won't call the function. You should add a componentDidMount method to call it afterwards.

Comment: I'm confused a little bit, because i did try this in the beginning, can you show me a complete snippet code ?